# Java 8, get the second (or any other position) element using Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I get the second (or any other position) element using `Stream` after `filter`?

Example (`student` is a `List`):

```
student.stream().filter(s->s.getName().startsWith("A")).findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

But instead of `findFirst()`, I need something else to get the second element.